# im trying to merge together 198 json files into one singular json, to then convert into a csv using python

Tags: python, json, api, csv

Each json is an individual API, which collate the same data but for different countries. I dont know how to combine the json's, and make it valid. Because there are 198 jsons, ive struggled to do so.

```
# // Opening web sites and web scraping: 
import requests

# // JSON. This helps us make JSON look prettier and easier to read
import json

# /// Files.  This is part of Collab - allows you to upload and download files
from google.colab import files

# // OS. Sometimes need this for finding working directory:
import os

url_base = "https://zerotracker.net/api/v1/countries/{}"

codes = []

for i in range(1, 199):
    code = "COU-{:04d}".format(i)
    codes.append(code)\

# // Begin a loop, dealing with series one by one:
for i in codes:  
   # // Build the URL for this iteration of the loop, and check what we are getting:
   URL = url_base.format(i)
   print(URL)

# // Set the base fileName:
file_base = "data_{}.json"

# // Begin a loop, dealing with each series, one by one:
for i in codes:  

   # // In what follows below I print the iteration of the loop we are on:
   # // This is not necessary but can be helpful, esp with long loops: 
   print("------Iteration Starts--------")
   print(i) 
  
   # // Build the URL for this iteration of the loop, and check what we are getting:
   URL = url_base.format(i)
   print(URL)
   
   # // Request the html from the URL:
   data = requests.get(URL).json()
   print(data)

   # // Set the filename, and check what we are getting:
   fileName = file_base.format(i)
   print(fileName)
   
   # // Add some white space to our output. (This is purely so we can see what is happening below clearly)
   print("------Iteration Ends--------")

   # /// Save the file:
   with open(fileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
     json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

   # /// Download the file to local machine:
   files.download(fileName)
```

Is there any way to do this? im using python.

Comment: Post some sample data? And how have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Okay, so **what exactly is the difficulty**? For example, if you had two input files instead of 198, would you be able to solve the problem? If not, then first you need to figure that out - **what does "merge together" actually mean**, for your specific problem? What needs to happen to the data, and what should the output be? On the other hand, if you *can* merge two files, then **why is it harder** to merge 198 files? Clearly, you already know how to use a loop. Did you try using a loop to repeat the "merge another file" code, until all the files are merged?

Answer (score 1):

It's farily simple to do this using pandas:

```
import requests

import pandas as pd


url_base = 'https://zerotracker.net/api/v1/countries'
codes = [f'COU-{i:04d}' for i in range(1, 199)]

dfs = []
for code in codes:
    try:
        url = f'{url_base}/{code}'
        print(f'Getting data from {url}...')
        data = requests.get(url).json()
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({k: [v] for k, v in data.items()}))
    except BaseException as e:
        print(f'Failed to get data for {url}\n{e}')

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('my_file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: is there a way of doing this if my API has headers?

Comment: For example...?